# Nodejs verify array strings

Tags: node.js

I have array of strings and I need to validate if incoming text id is included any of string in my array or not, how can I do that in node? (in php we usually do `in_array()`) but in node I don't have much experience.

`sample code`

```
var text = msg;

var myArray = [
  "123",
  "456"
];

if(text.id == myArray) {
 // true
} else {
 // false
}
```

**PS:** I am aware that `if(text.id == myArray)` is wrong, I just wrote that so you can get the idea of what I'm looking for.

#### Update

`My current code`

```
var myArray = [
    "182700619",
    "1566587158"
];
if (myArray.includes(msg.forward_from.id)) {
    console.log("msg2:", true);
} else {
    console.log("msg2:", false);
}
```

`my incoming message structure`

```
msg =  {
  message_id: 221,
  from: {
    id: 1566587158,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: 'Test User',
    username: 'testuser',
    language_code: 'en'
  },
  chat: {
    id: 1566587158,
    first_name: 'Test User',
    username: 'testuser',
    type: 'private'
  },
  date: 1619746446,
  forward_from: {
    id: 182700619,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    username: 'johndoe'
  },
  forward_date: 1619694506,
  text: 'tesing 01!'
}
```

Comment: If it's just an exact match, you should be able to do `myArray.includes(text.id)`

Comment: if([ '123', '456'].includes(text.d))

Comment: @Nick thank you I will text it and let you know

Comment: @Nick keeps returning `false` while my id is exist in array

Comment: Post your new code and we will be sure to help you out! Make sure to include the actual text value you're testing against

Comment: Looks like you're trying to compare a number to a string. You could try this: `myArray.includes(String(msg.forward_from.id))`

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo, but you're checking for `msg.forward_from.id` while your object is called `msg1` not `msg` also the string to number comparison as @Nick stated

Comment: @MohamedOraby no that because I removed `var text` it's fine and `msg1` is console name

Comment: @Nick `String` did the trick thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with below code, by using toString() method to convert the int to strings and then compare it.

```
msg = {
  message_id: 221,
  from: {
    id: 1566587158,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: 'Test User',
    username: 'testuser',
    language_code: 'en'
  },
  chat: {
    id: 1566587158,
    first_name: 'Test User',
    username: 'testuser',
    type: 'private'
  },
  date: 1619746446,
  forward_from: {
    id: 182700619,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    username: 'johndoe'
  },
  forward_date: 1619694506,
  text: 'tesing 01!'
}
var myArray = [
    "182700619",
    "1566587158"
];

console.log(typeof msg.forward_from.id);

if (myArray.includes(msg.forward_from.id.toString())) {
    console.log("msg2:", true);
} else {
    console.log("msg2:", false);
}
```

Output of the above code is below

```
$node main.js
number
msg2: true
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess `.toString()` that you suggested is same as `Nick` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67327057/nodejs-verify-array-strings#comment119004812_67327057)